# Getting a 500 internal server error ONLY on wp-admin/options-permalink.php

Tags: permalinks, htaccess, 500-internal-error

I have access to the admin panel, and everything works fine. I can click settings->reading and change anything I want to. But if I click settings->permalinks I get a 500 internal server error. Here's what I've tried:

I deleted the .htaccess file - nothing changed. I edited the .htaccess (because I am migrating this site to a new domain) and now I have all the page links working on the front end AND all the admin links EXCEPT permalinks. In other words, the front-facing portion of the website works. All of the admin features work. But if I click settings->permalinks, it takes me to /wp-admin/options-permalink.php but loads my theme's index.php template. Why?

I also re-installed all WordPress core files, to no avail.

Anyone have any ideas?

Here's my current .htaccess file:

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

Comment: Errors 500 are pretty much impossible to guess. Need server logs and _actual_ error. :(

Comment: If you already removed your htaccess file then you need to disable all plugins and reactivate them one by one, but what @rarst said is true. 500's are impossible to guess without the error message

Answer (score 0):

download a copy of wordpress.zip file then unzip it, copy /wp-admin/includes/update-core.php file and overwrite the one on the problem site. that worked for me.